# How to set a BindingErrorProcessor globally for all my Spring MVC controllers?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, security

I have a Spring MVC application where most of the controllers receive the HTTP parameters encapsulated in DTOs, nothing special:

```java
@RequestMapping(...)
public String handleUpdate(@Valid MyDto myDto, BindingResult bindingResult){...}
```

So the input Http parameters must have values that can be converted to the fields of my DTOs, when this doesn't happen and an binding exception is thrown Spring adds an Error with the exception message to the binding result. For example if `myDto` has an enum field but the Https param for that field has an invalid value.

The problem is these error messages get back to the UI and they can reveal information about the technologies, frameworks, libraries we use to a possible attacker. I need to hide these technical details behind a generic error message, say "invalid input".

I can add a `BindingErrorProcessors` to each controller's data binder like:

```java
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  binder.setBindingErrorProcessor(new MyBindingErrorProcessor());
}
```

but of course I don't what to do this for each controller class.

**Question** How can I set the BindingErrorProcessor for all my controllers? I think `@ControllerAdvice` only works for unhandled exceptions, maybe there's something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Just for others looking this up, `@ControllerAdvice` accepts `@InitBinder` methods:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyAdvice {
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
            binder.setBindingErrorProcessor(new BindingErrorProcessor() {
            @Override
            public void processMissingFieldError(String missingField, BindingResult bindingResult) {
                log.info("missing field " + missingField);
            }

            @Override
            public void processPropertyAccessException(PropertyAccessException ex, BindingResult bindingResult) {
                bindingResult.rejectValue(ex.getPropertyName(), "label.input.error", "label.general.error");
                log.info("property access exc. " + ex);
            }
    }
}
```

Method `processPropertyAccessException` will be called for conversion exceptions without adding any new Error to the bindingResult. You will have to add the error yourself.